# extracting data from a file and appending to the target file in linux using sed

Tags: linux, sed, append, extract

I want to extract some data from  files minimumThickness*.k and want to put it in the file results.txt.
The file mimimumThickness*.k has only double values in the first line.

The files minimumThickness.k are a series of files from 1 to hundred like

```
mimimumThickness1.k
mimimumThickness2.k
mimimumThickness3.k
. . .
. . .
mimimumThickness100.k
```

I used to following command to do it but was not successful.

```
 sed -n '/^[0-9.]*$/w results.txt' minimumThickness*.k
```

I could also use

```
for loop of i over 1 to hundred 

thickness=´cat minimumThickness$i.k | {print $1} ' | bc` 
echo $thickness 
thickess >> results.txt
```

kindly tell me about the problem with sed or suggest me better way of using sed. It would appreciate any elegent method.

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

[0-9.]* will match anything and so you may not be seeing expected result. You can try [0-9]*\.[0-9]* to get doubles (with some modifications).

Comment: `[0-9.]` doesn't match everything: `echo '0123asdf...' | sed 's/[0-9.]//g'` outputs `asdf`

Comment: The `-n` option is breaking it (e.g. `echo '0123asdf...' | sed -n 's/xyz//g'` prints nothing too). Try it without that.

Comment: > cat p1.txt  
    hello  
    hai  
    world  
    > cat p2.txt  
    hell  
    gag  
    9.9  
    > sed -n '/[0-9.]*/w output.txt' *.txt  
    > cat output.txt  
    hello  
    hai  
    world  
    hell  
    gag  
    9.9

Comment: That is something different: the `*` means that the pattern matches the empty string, and the empty string is a substring of everything. Try just `sed -n '/[0-9.]/w output.txt' *.txt` (without the `*`).

Comment: I now get what you are saying, Thanks. But for the question at hand, the answer works i.e replace the string given in the question's sed script. Any comments ..

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first line of each file:

```
head -n 1 minimumThickness*.k > results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -sn '1w results.txt' minimumThickness*.k
```

or

```
head -qn1 minimumThickness*.k > results.txt
```